# Unable to set and get $_GET in cakephp2

Tags: php, get, cakephp-2.0, http-request-parameters

I want to have a following  condition in my view.ctp. I want to get the parameters like "/?parameters=name&data=1" from a url and have it in my view. I want to set a $_GET. Where can I set it? Controller,Element,lor View? I read multiple tutorials but I still dont get how the $_GET works in Cakephp2. It would be great if you can give me sample or hints for dummies like me.

```
if(!empty($_GET['parameter'])){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET['parameter']` should be `$_GET['parameters']` in your code. For your `/?parameters=name&data=1`